# Having :before decoration not being part of the link

Tags: html, css

I'm building a link list:

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Wanting them to appear as a link bar I add the CSS:

```css
li { display: inline-block; }
```

Then, I would like to add a small content between the links using CSS, so :

```css
li :before { content: "+"; }
```

And here is the problem, the `+` is integrated to the `<a>` inside the `<li>`.

Why is it so ? I'm using `li:before`, not `a:before` !
How can I prevent it ?

Here's a JSFiddle showing it : http://jsfiddle.net/KY58h/

Comment: _“I'm using li:before, not a:before”_ – ironically, you’re not …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the syntax correct. Not

```
li :before {
```

but

```
li:before {
```

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/LsMq2/**

Answer (score 5):

Remove space between `li` & `:before` in your css.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a image for the purpose.

```
ul li + li {
    background:url('seperator.gif') no-repeat top left;
    padding-left: 10px
}
```